# Capture Storyboard Segue from application menu

Tags: swift, macos, storyboard, appkit

Is there a way to capture a segue generated from the menu in Application Scene?  My searches have not been forthcoming.

I have a Preferences menu item that is under the App name like most other Apple macOS applications, but unlike other segues, that segue is not firing the prepare or shouldPerformSegue methods.

I want to trap the segue like I do with other segues when they fire the above mentioned methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reliable way is:

1. Connect the segue from the main view controller to the Preferences controller.
2. In the main view controller create an `IBAction`. In the action call `performSegue`
3. Connect the menu item to the First Responder of the application scene (red cube). Select the IBAction.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I've been beating my head against the wall for the last two days trying to figure this out.